# How can I use rejava (reJ) to debug jave bytecode? (java byte code editor)

Tags: java, debugging, jvm, bytecode

I am using [rejava (reJ) to edit java bytecode](http://rejava.sourceforge.net/) directly. There seems to be support for setting break points and stepwise debugging.

I looked at the guide and webpage and there are no details about the debug functionality.

When I try to attach a JVM I get a system error
Screenshot:
http://s12.postimg.org/fd6s82t7h/javare_error.png

The Error is:

```
Cannot run "C:\Programs", the system cannot find the given file
```

Any ideas on how I can get the debugging features of reJ to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message you posted, it is evident that the problem is a space in the filename, causing `Program Files` (or `Program Files (x86)`) to get cut off at the space. Either stick your files in a different folder, or create a symlink that doesn't have spaces (requires admin permissions).